# No Acknowledgement from slave device

Tags: i2c, ftdi

I am using a FTDI's UM232H USB-I2C adapter to communicate with a MAX6615 temperature monitor device and DLVR pressure sensor. I developed an I2C routine to talk to these above mentioned devices. I am able to communicate successfully with the MAX6615 device but I'm not able to communicate with the DLVR sensor (it doesn't acknowledge). I also tried different clock speeds but no luck. The surprising part is that I am able to communicate with the same DLVR sensor using an Aardvark adapter. Now I am confused, whether it is a software or hardware issue. The code that I developed works with other I2C devices but not with DLVR sensor (which proves the code is good). On the other hand, I can able to read from the DLVR sensor through Aardvark (so I guess the hardware is good too).
The slave address I used is 0x28 as mentioned in the data sheet.

Any idea how to debug this issue?

Comment: use a logic scope, or an oscilloscope .... one puzzling thing though ... you said that the device does not acknowledge, that it returns 1 ... does that mean that it does return something?

Comment: It returned 1 Because , a slave  is required to pull the data line LOW to acknowledge receipt of the data. But it didn't pull the acknowledge line to low . So it returned 1.

Comment: your answer is not clear. just because the the data line stays high, it does not mean that the device is functioning  ... then a statement `returns 1` is made, it means to me that it actually returned a data byte that had a value of 1 ... if there was no actual data byte returned, then you should say that the device `did not acknowledge` and do not mention any numeric value.

Comment: Yea i got what you are saying . modified the question.

Comment: i wonder if the aardvark adapter adds something to the data stream. maybe if you forget to set something, it does it automatically. ... if your code is different between the aardvark and FTDI, maybe you used hex with one and decimal with the other.  .... what is the slave address of the MAX6615 ?

Comment: Also verify all interface specs; e.g. Data rate, Voltage, adequate delay time between bytes, common ground, ground noise.

Comment: I2C addresses are sometimes specified shifted by 1 bit (to make room for the R/W bit), sometimes not. How does the UM232H expect it to be? How is it specified in the DLVR data sheet? Try 0x14 and 0x50 as addresses as well.

Answer (score 2):

> The code that i developed works with other i2c device but not with DLVR sensor(**which proves the code is good**)

<sub>[My emphasis above.]</sub>

FYI the emphasised statement above is not true. This is a common troubleshooting fallacy, because it assumes all I²C devices behave in the same way.

Some I²C slaves are more, or less, tolerant to the *exact* behaviour of an I²C master. It is possible to have software (or hardware) bugs / limitations which only affect *some* devices, or which require specific I²C master programming. Therefore your statement that your code has been proved good because *one* type of I²C device works, is *false*. (Of course your code might, indeed, be suitable for both of your devices - but your test doesn't *prove* that.)

> Any idea how to debug this issue?

There are *many* possible techniques, depending on your available equipment, skills, experience, time, money etc.

Assuming that you have suitable test equipment, then using a simplified Kepner-Tregoe ATS (Analytical Trouble Shooting) approach, you have a very nice "IS" (i.e. problem) / "IS NOT" (i.e. no problem) pair of equivalent tests:

---

**IS** (i.e. test case shows the problem)

> using a FTDI's UM232H usb-i2c adapter [...] i couldn't be able to communicate with DLVR sensor.

---

**IS NOT** (i.e. test case shows no problem)

> i can able to communicate with the same DLVR sensor using Aardvark adapter.

---

[The ATS methodology, while too complex to explain in full here, includes comparing pairs of "IS" (i.e. *is* showing a deviation from correct behaviour = problem) vs. "IS NOT" (i.e. *is not* showing a deviation from correct behaviour = no problem) among other things.]

So gather oscilloscope traces (ideally), or logic analyser traces (if an oscilloscope is not available) from the "IS" (i.e. problem) and the "IS NOT" (i.e. no problem) test cases and **compare the traces**. That is a starting point.

Since one test works and the other doesn't work, then there *must* be one or more differences in what happens on the I²C bus, between the two test cases.

*Find the difference(s)!*

The next steps depend on what you find...

Note that logic analyser traces can't show some *electrical* problems, and this can mislead you in some situations. At least starting with a 'scope will allow you to confirm and validate the I²C waveform shape (rise/fall times), voltage levels (i.e. pull-ups to correct voltage for the devices on that bus) etc. If all of that is confirmed correct, and the problem is *definitely* at an I²C *protocol* level, rather than *electrical* level, then a logic analyser might be good enough for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Fully supporting SamGibson's answer I want to add a bit.
If DLVR device doesn't respond (acknowledge) to pattern generated by your code, then there is something wrong in your request (SW) or even in HW (whrong levels, bad edges, some glitches, etc) and DLVR doesn't tolerate it. May be wrong address, may be incompatible bus speed, something else...
So, the best way is to use oscilloscope and compare in detail good pattern sent by another master with your's one.